# Checking Background Jobs after Using Script to Submit

Tags: bash, shell-script

When I submit a job to the background using the below line, I have no issues using the `jobs` command to see the status.

```
nohup orca result0000.inp > result0000.out &
```

However, when I use a bash script to perform the same action, nothing is returned when using `jobs`. The reason I am using a script is because I will eventually use a loop to submit multiple jobs, and I would like to be able to see the status of the jobs as they run. This can be individual or one big jobs monitoring.

Is there a different approach I can take so I can monitor each job?

*ORCA is a quantum chemistry package*

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve this question, first time posting in this exchange!

Comment: Is `nohup` required?

Comment: @Panki It would be ideal, as I’m running it on a local machine and not a cluster.